# Notification when a certain exception has been raised in Java

Tags: java, exception, frameworks

I would like to know if there is a way where we can get notified when a certain exception has been thrown even if it was already caught.

I have an exception which is caught by the underlying framework which threw the exception. I have been trying to use this exception from outside of their try-catch (surrounding it essentially) as a trigger point to run some code and trying to find a way to do it.

Any way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: what does "notified" mean? can you simply change the code to catch it? if not, what are your restrictions? why do you tag this "frameworks"? (Your question is most likely about a particular framework, not the general idea; and each manages errors in a different way...)

Comment: @jidma the exception has been handled, so no point in me waiting to catch it. I want to know however if I can get a notification that such an exception had been raised.

Comment: @user1712863 so the exception has already been handled by the framework so you can't catch it in your code. Where do you see the exception ?

Comment: I see it making a comment in the log that such an exception was raised.

Answer (score 4):

You gave no context, so here some possibilities:

- set a breakpoint in the appropriate constructor and run in debug mode
- use aspects, e.g. aspectj or spring
- put your extensions in the exception's constructor
- put a try-catch around the code that causes the exception

P.S.: for the case you didn't know, you can catch `RuntimeExceptions` the same way you catch checked exceptions.

Comment: nice answer, covers all the basics given the lack of context

Comment: Am sorry if my question did not provide enough context. I am using a framework which throws an exception in one of the lower level class and handled in a higher level class of the same framework. My class which wraps these framework classes never gets this exception as it has already been handled. I am looking to track this exception when it has been raised.

Comment: In this case, you will need some aspects (point 2 in my list above)

Comment: I tried to do a little research on Aspects as well and happened to see the AfterThrowing aspect which seems to be relevant to exceptions. That aspect seems to be useful if a method exits by throwing an exception which would not help my case as my method does not exit with it. Anyway to intercept it before the it is handled and then allow it to continue execution?

Comment: Wow, you are fast on studying. Take a deeper look at the concepts of aspect oriented programming. I'm not into a framework, but from theory there is a point cut (i.e. a method or a constructor in your case) you declare to be executed before, after, or in between statements you define.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is already caught by the framework, there is no way of you catching it with a try-catch block.

You're trying to do this:

```
try {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Caught from the outside!");
}
```

which will fail, the exception's StackTrace will be printed, but the "Caught from the outside!" will not be printed. This is due to the fact that the exception thrown in the middle has already been caught, exceptions cannot be caught twice, or that would defeat the purpose of error handling; once an error is handled, no need to notify higher levels about it ;)

Comment: Yes. This is what i am looking for but not exactly this way. Is there a way I can hook into the JVM or any Event that lets me know that such an exception was thrown but it was handled as well. I just need to know that such an exception was thrown.

Comment: Don't believe so; that's too low level. Perhaps you could check by utilizing what the framework does? For example, if in it's catch block it does `System.err.println("Error!");` you could hook into the err PrintStream and catch that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have no access to the source, the exception is caught and handled outside of your scope of access, and you want to make it do something?

The only solution that's immediately apparent to me is PowerMock, a library allows you to override constructors and return objects of your own creation. It's typically only used in testing, and I discourage using it for any other purpose, but you could use it to replace all instances of that exception with an extension of the original exception, with your own code added in.